# Сайт на nginx без apache

Tags: apache, nginx, веб-сервер, сервер

Всем привет. Честно признаюсь, nginx еще не юзал. Но знаю, что его используют либо в качестве фронтенд-сервера, отдающего статику, либо в качестве проксирующего сервера.

**Собственно вопрос:**

Может ли nginx полностью заменить apache? То есть чтобы получилась связка Linux + Nginx + MySQL + PHP без Апача.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@mountpoint](/users/13008/mountpoint), да, через php-fpm. В большинстве случаев надо просто взять дефолтный конфиг (/etc/nginx/sites-available/default), поставить правильный рут/домен, раскомментировать нужный способ коннекта к fpm, залинковать конфиг в sites-enabled и перезагрузить nginx.

Comment: Важный момент, который надо учитывать в безапачёвых конфигурациях, — nginx не умеет файлы .htaccess (и не будет уметь, никогда), так-что настройки из них нужно переносить в конфиг виртуального хоста в nginx.